# addEventListener to array of images - modal in infinite scroll gallery

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, gallery, infinite-scroll

I want to add a modal to an "infinite" scroll image gallery I'm trying to create, so that when you click on each image the modal pops up linking to their respective source. I'm also trying to generate my images purely through my javascript without including any markup for the images in the HTML doc itself. I tried doing both "***files[i].addEventListener***" and "***img.addEventListener***" (to add it to all the images that have the ***".myImg"*** class) but I got this error for files[i] in the console and only got it to work for the very first image and none of the images after that using the img variable.

"***Uncaught TypeError: files[i].addEventListener is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.putImages (main.js:32)***"

Could anyone help me solve this, please? It would be really appreciated!

**Note: I'm trying to do this without jquery, if that's possible.**

JAVASCRIPT

```
// INFINITE SCROLL

// height of initial gallery, the original 13 images
var contentHeight = 600;
// height of visible page in browser
var pageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
// scrollbar position
var scrollPosition;
// next image
var n = 14;
// ajax
var ajaxCall = new XMLHttpRequest();

function putImages(){

if (ajaxCall.readyState==4)
  {
      if(ajaxCall.responseText){
            // to separate the file names, with semicolons
         var files = ajaxCall.responseText.split(";");
         // check if string isn't empty and add a thumbnail
          for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
              if(files[i] != ""){
                 document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += '<img class="myImg" src="/img/'+files[i]+'" width="198" height="198"/>';

                 // Get the modal
                 var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

                 // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                 var img = document.querySelector('.myImg');
                 var modalImg = document.querySelector(".modalContent");
                 img.addEventListener('click', function() {
                     modal.style.display = "block";
                     modalImg.src = this.src;
                 })

                 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                 var span = document.querySelector(".close")[0];
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

//SCROLL

function scroll(){

if(navigator.appName == "")
    scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
else
    scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

if((contentHeight - pageHeight - scrollPosition) < 600){
// reference to the php file
    var url="getImages.php?n="+n;
// send ajax request
    ajaxCall.open("GET",url,true);
    ajaxCall.send();
// put the images on the page
    n += 13;
    ajaxCall.onreadystatechange=putImages;
    contentHeight += 600;
}
}
```

HTML

```
    <!-- Header -->
<div class ="container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-12 header">
      <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.querySelector('.modal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modalContent">

</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Image Gallery -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="gallery">

    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
/* get directory for thumbnail images */
$dir = "img";
/* check if directory exists */
if(is_dir($dir)){
    /* open directory if directory exists */
    if($dd = opendir($dir)){
        while (($f = readdir($dd)) !== false)
            if($f != "." && $f != "..")
                $files[] = $f;
        closedir($dd);
    }

/* to create infinite effect, b/c of lack of infinite images cycle must restart */
$n = $_GET["n"];
$response = "";
    for($i = $n; $i<$n+13; $i++){
        $response = $response.$files[$i%count($files)].';';
    }
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is because when attaching it to files[i] that is something that isn't part of your DOM, it is the text of the src location of your image. So it can't attach there. And the img will only ever return the first one because you aren't looping through all of those. So you need to actually add the event listener to the `<img>`s.
You could add an id to each img as you add it:
`document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += '<img class="myImg" src="/img/'+files[i]+'" width="198" height="198" id="file'+i+'" />';`
and then add the listener to that, like:
`var img = document.getElementById("file"+i);
img.addEventListener()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now my problem is that it is only applying to the last image.

Comment: Can you check your output DOM and see what the id for each img is? Sounds like maybe they are all the same (and my setting of the id was wrong)?

Comment: The id for each goes from 0-12, so file0, file1...file11, file12. Then, because I've created this loop of 13 images, the ids start again, file0, file1, etc. Each one corresponds to their correct image, but because of this loop of 13 images, to create the "infinite" gallery, there are repeating ids.

Comment: ok, so use `n` instead of `i`, that is continually incrementing, right?

Comment: so, in what instances would I replace `i` with `n`? When I'm creating the ids and then selecting them to add the eventlistener? I'm still new to javascript, sorry.

Comment: yes, exactly. you're ids all need to be unique. So if n is a unique counter than using that instead of i (that repeats 0-13) is the way to do that. So basically just replace it in the stuff I was suggesting

Comment: when I replaced `i` with `n` in those three instances you mentioned before, it gave me a 404 error for the images. If I replaced all of the `i`s with `n` I got the same problem as before, where the modal only works for the last image, `file12`. I figured that would happen but gave it a shot anyway.

Comment: so i added a unique counter `var picCount = 0;` `document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += '<img class="myImg" src="/img/'+files[i]+'" width="198" height="198" id="file'+picCount+'" />'; picCount++;` and while each image now has a unique id, the modal still only works for image with id `file12`. Again, `file12` is the last image in the loop.

Comment: when i did `var img = document.getElementById("file"+picCount);`  i got this error in the console "**main.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.putImages (main.js:38)**"

Comment: so you have unique id for all elements, and you successfully add an event listener to the last one of your loop each time, despite getting like 26 or 39 images with unique ids? and this is with the `document.getElementById` with `picCount` put in it? I'm at a bit of a loss then. It might be worth breaking it up to see if you can get it working. As in, have a separate function for adding the listeners after this one executes that simply does a `var imgs =  getElementsByClassName('myImg')` and then loop that:
`for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
 inputs[i].addEventListener(...);
}`

Comment: seems like I'll have to find a different solution. thanks for the help anyway!